# Flow query isn't getting a record that a SOQL query has no problem getting

Tags: visual-workflow

I have multiple queries in the flow that are set up the exact same. Im not getting an error, the flow runs through fine and does what it's supposed to. It's just not getting the records needed, and therefore leaving items out that need to be iterated over.

[SOQL Query getting the correct list of Ids](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lvNk.png)

[image: Flow query not getting the same list of Ids as the SOQL query]

Comment: So...did you run debug on the Flow and verify that the contents of `{!Opportunity_Record.AccountId}` are what you expect? and that such Campaign Company recs are all status = Active.

Comment: Yes, I got the Id for the query from the flow debug and used that to verify that it is what i was expecting.

Comment: does running user of Flow have CRUD access/sharing access to the records?

Comment: Yes, the user Im logged in as in Sys Ad and has access to all records.